# How To Inject Service Into Angular 1.5 Component (No Typescript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a service that I want to pass into a Component in Angular 1.5.  I'm not using Gulp or TypeScript.

This is the service:

```js
(function() {'use strict';
angular.module('flavorApplication')
  .component('app', {
   templateUrl: "app/app.component.html",
    controllerAs: "vm",
   controller: function AppController() {
```

This is the Component:

```js
(function() {'use strict';
angular.module('flavorApplication')
  .component('app', {
   templateUrl: "app/app.component.html",
    controllerAs: "vm",
   controller: function AppController('DataService')
```

This didn't work. I also tried:

`controller: ['DataService', function AppController('DataService')`

This also didn't work. Keep in mind I'm new to angular and just getting my feed under me.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't need the single quotes. `controller: function AppController(DataService)`

Comment: @Lex can you reply that as the answer? That was it. I upvoted and accidentally deleted the vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes.

```
controller: function AppController(DataService)
```

Comment: that's the beauty of removing array syntax , not more confusion :)